# Working Schedule in C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to write a small program in c# where I can display the work schedule of apart time night guard.

The idea is that the guard must work every 3rd weekend starting week-1

The guard should also work "night-shift" every 5th week starting starting week-6

I have some trouble implementing this in code so I thought I'd ask some kind soul for help.

This is what I have so far :)

```
int[] _numbers = new int[52];
List<int> _weekends = new List<int>();
List<int> _nights = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < _numbers.Length; i++)
{
     i += 2;
     _weekends.Add(i);
}

int num = 0;

foreach (int j in _weekends)
{
     num = j + 2;

     Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Comment: Where is the logic? What is your approach to tackle this problem? You have to show a little effort.

Comment: Did you not see my code block ???

Comment: First I have an array called _numbers populated with 52
then I have declared list arrays called _weekends and _nights

inside a for loop - I increment i by 2 and add that to the _weekends list array. The result is that 18 items will be added to list array

inside a for-each loop I make it so that for every item inside _weekends I will increment num by 2 and write that out to the console

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll give you some hints.

1. If the guy should work every third weekend starting week 1... why are you adding 2?

   - 1st weekend - works
   - 2nd weekend - off
   - 3rd weekend - off
   - 4th weekend - works (this is the 3rd weekend after the last one. Note this is 3 weekends after the last time he worked, not 2...

Next,

1. Night shifts ... you don't have that in your code yet, but it is same logic:

   - Week 1 - off
   - Week 2 - off
   - Week 3 - off
   - Week 4 - off
   - Week 5 - off
   - Week 6 - works ... how many weeks should you add for the next time he works?

Now, your array of 52 denotes both weeks and weekends, each number representing I assume week of the year.

You don't really need to do any adding. You can actually just loop through your 52 numbers, and have two conditions in there, one for weekends, one for nights.

It's a math question, really...

How do you get 1, 4, 7, etc for weekends, and 6, 11, 16 etc. for nights? There is a repeatable pattern here and if you remove 1 from each set, you gett 3, 6, 9, ..., and 5, 10, 15, etc. These are simple sets that are easily divisible. As you loop you can check each number, see if it's divisible without a remainder by the multiplication factor in each set (i.e., what is the multiplication factor that gets you a set 3, 6, 9, etc. (hint: same as number of days between shifts). When there's no remainder you hit the jackpot.

Say you have a loop (you don't really need numbers in a List by the way, is that a requirement?:

```
var numberOfWeeksInYear = 52 // define it so you don't use a "magic number"
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfWeeksInYear; i++) // easier here to use for vs. foreach because you can use the value of i to get your calculations done
{
    // Condition for weekends
    // if (i is divisible by 3 with no remainder) you get 3, 6, 9, etc.
    // that formula plus 1 gets you 4, 7, etc which is the weekend shift 
    // hint: Look into the mod operator or Math.DivRem()
    // fill in the blanks.

    // Condition for nights
    // Ah! same thing, you need 6, 11, 16, etc.
    // Well if you divide i by 5 and add 1 then you get that number. Your solution is the same
    // as above...
}
```

Now, if you MUST use `foreach` instead of for, then just keep your List numbers and use the actual value in your calculations:

```
foreach(var number in _numbers)
{
    // if number is divisible by .... etc.
}
```

This should point you in the right direction without giving you the answer outright.
Good luck!

Comment: I will try it out and then let you know how it went 

Thanks